# How can I make preview stop wrapping around when paging?

Tags: pdf, preview

If I open a PDF document in Preview and navigate through the pages normally using <kbd>Page down</kbd> and <kbd>Page up</kbd>, then if I hold down the keys to trigger auto-repeat, when I reach the bottom (or top) of the document, Preview wraps around and shows me the top (or bottom) again.  For example, if I press and hold <kbd>Page down</kbd> to page forward, then when it reaches the end of the document, it doesn't stop there; it starts back at the top, going around in a kind of loop.  The behavior *only* happens if I set my key repeat rate (in system preferences) to the maximum possible.

What could cause this, and how can I prevent this from happening (short of reducing the keyboard repeat rate), so that Preview stops when it reaches the top or bottom of a document?

This is on macOS 10.13.6, on an iMac. This happens both with a Kinesis Pro keyboard and a bog-standard Dell USB keyboard; both have dedicated page up/down keys. In Preview settings, "opening for the first time" is set to continuous scroll. Example of a random PDF file where it happens: https://www.apple.com/procurement/pdf/impact-accelerator.pdf  Here is a video recording showing the behavior: https://share.getcloudapp.com/8LubXNo5

Comment: Tested with Ortek and Dell keyboards using Page Up/Page Down keys under macOS 10.13.6 and cannot reproduce the behavior you've described.

Comment: Now we'er getting somewhere... with default settings I cannot reproduce, but tweaked up I can reproduce.

Comment: High five! Now I feel less nutty :-)

Comment: RE: "I mean, the answer I'm trying to get is not "reduce the repeat rate"" -- Do you need to have it set all the way to Fast when in Preview or mainly other apps?

Comment: That's my preference, yes, though I don't need it for Preview per se. If there was a way to selectively change it for different apps, I would

Comment: RE: "If there was a way to selectively change it for different apps, I would" --  Well not natively with **macOS** alone, however I'm looking for a programatic solution to change it lower just when **Preview** has keyboard focus. Give me a little bit to see what it would take to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still an issue in Ventura 13.6.2 and I had not changed the repeat rate from the default (one tick from the right). You don't need to hold down the pagedown key for this to happen either, so no longer tied to key repeat. Changing the repeat rate didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discovered, this issue currently only exists with **Preview** when the **Key Repeat** *slider* on the **Keyboard** *tab* of the **Keyboard** *pane* in **System Preferences** is set to **Fast**, where the *slider* is all the way to the right. By default it's one position from the right.

This is a *workaround* solution that sets the **Key Repeat** *slider* to the default position when **Preview** is activated, and to **Fast** when it's deactivated, (i.e. given/lost keyboard/mouse focus).

It uses the *third-party application* [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org) along with a bit of **Lua** *code* to watch for **Preview** being activated/deactivated, and an **AppleScript** *script* using **UI Scripting** to adjust the **Key Repeat** *slider* on the **Keyboard** *tab* of the **Keyboard** *pane* in **System Preferences**.

The *example* **Lua** *code* and *example***AppleScript** *code*, shown further below, was tested under **macOS High Sierra** and **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

- <sup>Note that the download and install instructions assume **Safari** and default *preference* **[√] Open “safe” files after downloading** checked.</sup>

### Download *Hammerspoon*

- https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/releases/latest
- Click the **Hammerspoon-n.n.nn.zip** link.

---

### Install *Hammerspoon*

- Open the **Downloads** *folder* and drag and drop the **Hammerspoon** *application bundle* into **Applications**.
- Before you open **Hammerspoon**, add it to: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**

Open **Hammerspoon** from **Applications** or **Spotlight**, then:

From the **Hammerspoon** menu, [image] on the **menu bar**, click it, then click **Preferences…**, and set them as follows:

**Hammerspoon Preferences**

**Behavior:**

- **[√] Launch Hammerspoon at login**
- **[√] Check for updates**
- **[ ] Show dock icon**
- **[√] Show menu icon**
- **[ ] Keep Console window on top**
- **[ ] Send crash data (requires restart)**

**Accessibility: Accessibility is enabled. Your all set!** 
         **Enable Accessibility** (Should be grayed out.)

Close **Hammerspoon Preferences**.

---

### Adding the Lua code to *Hammerspoon*

Open the **Hammerspoon** configuration *file* by clicking the **Open Config** *command* from the **Hammerspoon** menu, [image] on the **menu bar**.

Add the *example* **Lua** *code* to the **init.lua** configuration *file* and save the *document*, then close it.

---

### *Example* **Lua** *code*:

```Lua
function applicationPreviewWatcher(appName, eventType, appObject)
    if (eventType == hs.application.watcher.activated) then
        if (appName == "Preview") then
            local asFile = "/.hammerspoon/Scripts/ChangeKeyRepeatValue.applescript"
            local ok, status = hs.osascript.applescriptFromFile(os.getenv("HOME") .. asFile)
        end
    end
    if (eventType == hs.application.watcher.deactivated) then
        if (appName == "Preview") then
            local asFile = "/.hammerspoon/Scripts/ChangeKeyRepeatValue.applescript"
            local ok, status = hs.osascript.applescriptFromFile(os.getenv("HOME") .. asFile)
        end
    end 
end
appPreviewWatcher = hs.application.watcher.new(applicationPreviewWatcher)
appPreviewWatcher:start()
-- appPreviewWatcher:stop()
```

---

### Adding the AppleScript *script* to *Hammerspoon*

In **Terminal**:

```
mkdir -p ~/.hammerspoon/Scripts
touch ~/.hammerspoon/Scripts/ChangeKeyRepeatValue.applescript
open ~/.hammerspoon/Scripts/ChangeKeyRepeatValue.applescript
```

Close: **Terminal** <sub>(Assumes no errors from previous *commands*.)</sub>

In **Script Editor**:

Add the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, to the opened **ChangeKeyRepeatValue.applescript** *document*, then save it, and close the *document*.

Close: **Script Editor**

**NOTE:** With that done, you can now click the **Reload Config** *command* on the **Hammerspoon** menu, [image] on the **menu bar**.

This should now toggle the **Key Repeat** *slider* on the **Keyboard** *tab* of the **Keyboard** *pane* in **System Preferences** as **Preview** is activated/deactivated.

---

### *Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # 
--  # NOTE: Hammerspoon does not allow the use of the
--  #       AppleScript line continuation character.
--  #       Therefore code must be written in long form.
--  #       It also doesn't like the use of some characters
--  #       such as symbols for modifier keys and others
--  #       in comments and possibly in code as well.
--  # 
--  # ChangeKeyRepeatValue.applescript
--  #
--  # Change the value of Key Repeat on the Keyboard tab 
--  # of the Keyboard pane in System Preferences. 
--  # 

--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Get the name of the frontmost application.

tell application "System Events"
    set appName to name of process 1 whose frontmost is true
end tell

--  # Open System Preferences to the Keyboard tab of the Keyboard pane.

tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "keyboardTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell

--  # Change the value of Key Repeat as coded.

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        set i to 0
        repeat until exists slider 2 of tab group 1 of window 1
            delay 0.1
            set i to i + 1
            if i > 30 then return
        end repeat
        if appName = "Preview" then
            set value of slider 2 of tab group 1 of window 1 to 6.0
        else
            set value of slider 2 of tab group 1 of window 1 to 7.0
        end if
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.1
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

---

**Notes:**

As currently coded, it assumes when **Hammerspoon** is first loaded that the **Key Repeat** *slider* on the **Keyboard** *tab* of the **Keyboard** *pane* in **System Preferences** is set to **Fast** and **Preview** is **not** *frontmost*.

It is normal to see the **System Preferences** icon on the **Dock** bounce once briefly showing the open indicator under it when **Hammerspoon** sees that **Preview** has been activated/deactivated. It's running the **AppleScript** *script* to change the position of the **Key Repeat** *slider* on the **Keyboard** *tab* of the **Keyboard** *pane* in **System Preferences**. This on my system takes less than a second. If I can find a way to programmatically behind the scene make this change without having to use **UI Scripting** with **AppleScript** I will update the *code* and notify the OP.

There is an issue with this *workaround* when manually clicking on **System Preferences** in the **Dock** when **Preview** is *frontmost*. To manually open **System Preferences** from the **Dock** when **Preview** is *frontmost* you need to set *focus* away from **Preview** first before clicking on **System Preferences** in the **Dock**. The behavior when **Preview** is *frontmost* and  manually trying to open **System Preferences** from the **Dock** results in **System Preferences** being opened and closed, bouncing on the **Dock**, without further user interaction. (I'll see what I can do to resolve this issue, although I think it's a nature of the beast type bug that one will just need to be aware of and live with for the benefit of what this solution provides.)

<sub>I am not affiliated with the developers of **Hammerspoon**, just a satisfied user of the product.</sub>

---

Note: The *example* **Lua** and **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.

Comment: Ok, that's pretty amazing.